# Is there a more efficient way of coding than having these if statements?

Tags: c#, if-statement

For part of my code there is section which is the same if statement over and over again the only difference being one of the variables. Is there a better way of structuring my code?

```
if (buttonArray[m, j].BackColor == levelTwo && buttonArray[m, a].BackColor == levelTwo
 && buttonArray[i, j].BackColor == levelTwo)

{
    buttonArray[i, j].BackColor = levelThree;
    buttonArray[m, j].BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    buttonArray[m, a].BackColor = Color.Transparent;
}

if (buttonArray[m, j].BackColor == levelThree && buttonArray[m, a].BackColor == levelThree
 && buttonArray[i, j].BackColor == levelThree)
{
    buttonArray[i, j].BackColor = levelFour;
    buttonArray[m, j].BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    buttonArray[m, a].BackColor = Color.Transparent;
}

if (buttonArray[m, j].BackColor == levelFour && buttonArray[m, a].BackColor == levelFour
 && buttonArray[i, j].BackColor == levelFour)
{
    buttonArray[i, j].BackColor = levelFive;
    buttonArray[m, j].BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    buttonArray[m, a].BackColor = Color.Transparent;
}

if (buttonArray[m, j].BackColor == levelFive && buttonArray[m, a].BackColor == levelFive
 && buttonArray[i, j].BackColor == levelFive)
{
    buttonArray[i, j].BackColor = levelSix;
    buttonArray[m, j].BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    buttonArray[m, a].BackColor = Color.Transparent;
}

if (buttonArray[m, j].BackColor == levelSix && buttonArray[m, a].BackColor == levelSix
 && buttonArray[i, j].BackColor == levelSix)
{
    buttonArray[i, j].BackColor = levelSeven;
    buttonArray[m, j].BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    buttonArray[m, a].BackColor = Color.Transparent;
}

if (buttonArray[m, j].BackColor == levelSeven && buttonArray[m, a].BackColor == levelSeven && buttonArray[i, j].BackColor == levelSeven)
{
    buttonArray[i, j].BackColor = levelEight;
    buttonArray[m, j].BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    buttonArray[m, a].BackColor = Color.Transparent;
}
```

Comment: you can do a Switch(){ case }

Comment: For performance, look up your buttons from the array and declare them in scope. This saves you from 20 lookups in the array

Comment: what's this levelFive/Six business? If that was an array, it'd be a simple matter of having `level[5]` and stuff all of that into a loop.

Comment: Looking at just this If block it is hard to say what you can do to optimize it. Can you please give us more detail (code) perhaps.

Comment: levelFive, levelSix are colour variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a method (I don't know the type of Level though...)

```
private void CheckLevel(int levelIndex)
{
    if (buttonArray[m, j].BackColor == levelArray[levelIndex] && buttonArray[m, a].BackColor == levelArray[levelIndex] 
        && buttonArray[i, j].BackColor == levelArray[levelIndex])
    {
        buttonArray[i, j].BackColor = levelArray[levelIndex + 1];
        buttonArray[m, j].BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        buttonArray[m, a].BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    }

}
```

and in your code:

```
CheckLevel(LevelTwoIndex);
CheckLevel(LevelThreeIndex);
CheckLevel(LevelFourIndex);
```

Comment: levelOne,two etc being a colour variable.

Comment: This. If you see code that does the same thing, it usually is better to extract the logic into a method. The `CheckLevel` method calls are much easier to read and understand.

Comment: Ok, then for the +1 to work, the levels should be in an array and the index is passed

Comment: Ah of course yeah stick them into an array. What type of arrays would they be though because they will be storing "colors"

Comment: An array can contain any type. Like an int[], you can have an array Color[] myArray = new Color[8]

Comment: Ah nice to know. I'm new to c# so i wasn't sure what the "rule" was.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like what you're trying to do is cycle the color of all of these buttons each time something happens.

Here is a more significant re-write of that concept:

First well start by creating a `private Queue<Color> colors = new Queue<Color>();`  This will contain all of the colors that you are cycling between in the order that they are used.

We can populate it when the form is first created:

```
colors.Enqueue(Color.Red);
colors.Enqueue(Color.Yellow);
colors.Enqueue(Color.Violet);
//Add other colors
```

Now we just need a method to apply the "next" color to any number of controls:

```
public void ApplyNextColor(params Control[] controls)
{
    Color nextColor = colors.Dequeue();
    colors.Enqueue(nextColor);//add to end so that we cycle; 
    //you can optionally remove and do nothing if there are not items.

    foreach (Control control in controls)
        control.BackColor = nextColor;
}
```

We can then call this from, for example, a button click event or a timer tick event:

```
ApplyNextColor(buttonArray[m, j], buttonArray[m, a]);
```

Comment: ApplyNextColor(buttonArray[m, j], buttonArray[m, a]);

So this line would change the colours of the buttons in that array, to the colour above it in the queue so to speak. So level1 to level2? 

If so how would you make it go backwards or to a specific colour in the queue?

Comment: @RobertMason It depends on the specifics of what you want.  If you don't always go in one direction you could potentially just store the colors in a `List` and have an integer index to that list that moves up/down, as long as you make sure to wrap around when you hit either end of the list.  If you have more complex logic for determining the color you'd need to explain it.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (buttonArray[m, j].BackColor == buttonArray[m, a].BackColor 
        && buttonArray[m, a].BackColor == buttonArray[i, j].BackColor) {
    if (buttonArray[m, j].BackColor == levelThree) { // or a switch - case
        ....
    }
}
```